# How to take photo from webcam every one minute?

Tags: c#, webcam, aforge, webcam-capture

I'm trying to take a snapshot through my webcam.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video;

namespace WebCamShot
{
    class Program
    {
        static FilterInfoCollection WebcamColl;
        static VideoCaptureDevice Device;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebcamColl = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Capture Photo !");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Device = new VideoCaptureDevice(WebcamColl[0].MonikerString);
            Device.NewFrame += Device_NewFrame;
            Device.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap Bmp = (Bitmap)e.Frame.Clone();
            Bmp.Save("D:\\Foo\\Bar.png");
            Console.WriteLine("Snapshot Saved.");
            /*
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping ...");
            Device.SignalToStop();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped .");
            */
        }
    }
}
```

It works well, but now I want to use my code for taking a snapshot every one minute.

Due to this reason, I added this line of code: `Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60); // 1000 Milliseconds (1 Second) * 60 == One minute.`

Unfortunately, This line doesn't giving me the wanted result - It still taking the snapshots like earlier, but it just saving the photos in the file every minute. What I actually want to do, is that my code will trigger the "Device_NewFrame" event every one minute.

How can I do it? I will glad to get some help.. Thhank You !

**EDIT:** As Armen Aghajanyan offered, I added timer to my code.
This timer Initializes the device object every one minute, registers the new Device object to the Device_NewFrame event and starts the activity of the Device.
After that, I'm uncommented this code in the event's body:

```
Console.WriteLine("Stopping ...");
Device.SignalToStop();
Console.WriteLine("Stopped .");
```

Now the code is taking a snapshot every one minute.

Comment: Could you take the output of the event and draw the picture in a picture box while not showing the frames being sent from the camera device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Timer.Elapsed event. The implementation is straight forward and clean.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
 private static void TimerThread(object obj)
    {
        int delay = (int)obj;
        while (true)
        {
            takePhotos = true;
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
    }
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebcamColl = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Capture Photo !");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Device = new VideoCaptureDevice(WebcamColl[0].MonikerString);
        Device.NewFrame += Device_NewFrame;
        Device.Start();
        Thread timer=new Thread(TimerThread);
         timer.Start(60000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
    {
       if(!takePhotos)return;
        Bitmap Bmp = (Bitmap)e.Frame.Clone();
        Bmp.Save("D:\\Foo\\Bar.png");
        takePhotos=false;
        Console.WriteLine("Snapshot Saved.");
        /*
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping ...");
        Device.SignalToStop();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped .");
        */
    }
```

Declare a static variable takePhotos and initialize with true